# laravel 8 -> authorization with jwt and postman

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, jwt, authorization

I'm building an API with Laravel8 and use postman , Also I use JWT for authentication and want to authorization for creating a new post , I want to be able to create a new post only when the user is an admin or author , so I create a middleware `AdminLevelAuthorization`  and in kernel I added it as `'auth.level'`

So I put this middleware for my route in api.php : `Route::apiResource('posts' , PostController::class)->middleware('auth.level:admin,author');`

In postman I logged in and saved my token, I just don't know how use this token for authorization

When I go to this route `http://localhost:8000/api/posts` in postman and in authorization part , bearer token type I enter my token in token field , so it says :
 `"You are unauthorized to access this resource"`

I don't know I'm wrong or not in entering token or my middleware is the problem

This is my middleware :

```php
class AdminLevelAuthorization
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$levels)
    {
        try {
            //Access token from the request    
            $token = JWTAuth::parseToken();//Try authenticating user
            $user = $token->authenticate();

        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
            //Thrown if token has expired
            return $this->unauthorized('Your token has expired. Please, login again.');

        } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
            //Thrown if token invalid
            return $this->unauthorized('Your token is invalid. Please, login again.');

        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            //Thrown if token was not found in the request.
            return $this->unauthorized('Please, attach a Bearer Token to your request');
        }

        //If user was authenticated successfully and user is in one of the acceptable levels, send to next request.
        if ($user && in_array($user->levels, $levels)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return $this->unauthorized();
    }

    private function unauthorized($message = null){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $message ? $message : 'You are unauthorized to access this resource',
            'success' => false
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Since your `unauthorized` method is called without a message, it seems like your user does not own the `$levels`. 
Assuming that `$levels` and `$user->levels` are both arrays you need to perform a different level-verification since `in_array($array,$array2)` does not work. In case `$user->levels` is a string you should probably double-check if your code-logic is actually working properly

Comment: omfg T_T Look at my stupid mistake :") $user->levels is the problem. it must be $user->level.. thank you so much :"))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in `s` for `user->levels` it must be `$user->level`